# Sorting an array of polyLines

Tags: c#, algorithm, geometry

I have the following two classes

```
public class PointClass
{
    double x, y, z;
}
```

and

```
public class PolyLineClass
{
    PointClass startPoint;
    PointClass endPoint;
}
```

and an array of PolyLineClasses

```
polyLineArray[];
```

Assume that if we connect all the lines in the polyLineArray in some kind of order, we obtain a closed, nonselfintersecting curve.

For example

```
                  startPt  endPt
polyLineArray[0]: (0,0,0) (1,0,0)
polyLineArray[1]: (0,1,0) (0,0,0)
polyLineArray[2]: (1,1,0) (0,1,0)
polyLineArray[3]: (1,0,0) (1,1,0)
```

If we traverse through the array in 0->3->2->1 order, we create a closed curve(in this simple case, a square).
Right now, what I have is the following algorithm:

```
1) int i = 0; 
2) Get the endPt of polyLineArray[i];
3) search through the array for an element with index j such that 
   polyLineArray[i].endPoint == polyLineArray[j].startPoint.
4) i = j; Repeat from step2 until all elements in the array have been visited.
```

The above algorithm is O(scary). Is there a more efficient way to do the sorting?
If language does matter, I am coding in c#.

Comment: Use address variable near x,y,z such that x,y,z,addr that points to next polypoint then this will be O(n) or you can just pre-sort them into another array then use that sorted array so you dont have to sort each time(which is O(1))

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the convex hull problem.  Searching that on google/wikipedia should give you some good info on general algorithms to use.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Could you elaborate more on an answer? I'm confused on what you mean by your comment.

Comment: @Servy The curve created by the points are not necessarily convex. It could be concave so I don't think the convex hull problem would apply here, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Calpis Then you have the concave hull problem.  Same advice.  Both are a thing.  Go to Google/Wikipedia.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/concave-hull-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class

```
public class EndPoint {
    PointClass point ;
    int lineIndex ;
}
```

and an array

```
EndPoint endPoints[] ;
```

whose length is twice that of `polyLineArray`.

For each end point `e` of line `i` create an EndPoint `{e,i}` and add it to the `endPoints` array.  Then sort this array in `point` element order.  (The points can be sorted/compared component-wise).

After the sort is complete, you can traverse the array and pick off EndPoints.  These will come in pairs, where the points are equal, but the line indices will point to the lines which join at that point. You can walk the sorted EndPoint array picking up a linked series of PolyLines.

Answer (score 1):

consider using `(x,y,z)` as vertex labels for a graph whose edges are precisely the line segments `(startPoint, endPoint)` from your polyline array. define a lexicographic order on the vertex labels. build the graph while iterating once through the polyline array in `O(n log n)`. detect a cycle of length `n` in `O(n)`, total `O(n)`.

Comment: Could you explain what vertex labels are? Also, since the points are distributed in 3d space, how can a lexicographic order be defined?

Comment: 'vertex labels' are names of graph vertices. you can label graph vertices any way you like but while creating the graph you have to keep track of vertices that already exist, and vertices n the algo are identified by their coordinate tuple. therefore you may just use them as idenifying labels. lexicographic order in 3d (in fact in `IR^n`) can be defined by first ordering by x coordinates, then by y, and finally by z. example: (1,2,3) < (3,2,1); (1,2,3) < (1,3,2);